# post/tweet message from my ios app to fb and twitter

Tags: ios, facebook, post, twitter

I want to post/tweet message frm my iOS app.

for Twitter

```
  NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"twitter://post? text=%@",posttextview.text]];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url])
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

I am getting post screen with my message

for Facebook

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb://publish/profile/me?text=%@",posttextview.text]];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication]canOpenURL:url])
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:url];
```

i am not getting post screen in for this FB custom Url

1.Am i going any thing wrong in Fb Url.

2.Is there any way to post/tweet directly with out showing post screen after redirect

3.if apps are not installed i want to do it in browser is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to Sign in facebook in your iPhone settings..

Comment: i have facebook app in my app, it opens but no message, only showing newsfeed section